# Download location for MAPI33.dll?

Tags: mapi

From where can I download MAPI33.dll. I got the link http://www.mapi33.adexsolutions.com/ from a site but it seems this is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find an older version here:

http://g8.cx/mapi/

The newest version must be bought.

I cite:

> The following code samples might be
>   obsolete. They might not work with
>   current version of the mapi33 dll,
>   though they will still work using the
>   out-of-date (but quite well-working
>   and free) version of the mapi33 dll
>   included in the samples zip file.
>
> To get up-to-date information about
>   the mapi33 dll and to buy the most
>   recent version, visit the mapi33
>   website at 
>   http://www.mapi33.adexsolutions.com/

The link to the company homepage seem to be outdated.

The samples link however is not. It can be found under section 4 there or as a direct link here:

http://g8.cx/mapi/ExtendedMapiWithCSharp_sourcecode.zip

I verified that the samples link was working when I wrote this.