# Read mail from Microsoft Exchange Server with attachment

Tags: email, exchange-server, mapi

I need to read mail with attachment from my company's mail server. Its a Microsoft Exchange Server. I also have  to save the attachment(its a text attachment).
I am working with java. So I am expecting a java code or API for this. But if no reliable java source is available then I am ready to work with C#.net equipment. 
I am trying with MAPI33 dll from [Download location for MAPI33.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362359/download-location-for-mapi33-dll). But still unable to read mail.
If there are any better solution, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RDO part of [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/). It is a COM library that wraps MAPI and that is really good. You can use [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) (Java COM bridge) to do the COM magic. Just remember that MAPI for Exchange only comes in 32 bit, so your will need to run from a 32 bit JVM. JACOB is open source while Outlook Redemption have a developer version that you can try out first.

In Exchange 2007 and 2010 you will also need to install the [MAPI & CDO distributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&displaylang=en) because Exchange MAPI is no longer shipped with exchange.